# what units is parameter K measured in, in a MOSFET?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I know how to work out the constant K from the equation:

K = Id / ( Vgs - Vth ) ^ 2

but I can't seem to find what units it is measured in, any help would be appreciated thank you,

I think it might be Siemens / V or Siemens / m?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The units are \$\dfrac{\text{A}}{\text{V}^2}\$. It is the relationship between current and voltage so there is no point in looking for some other arcane unit to use with it.